# How to automatically fill the value of password field in newly tab using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi i want to open new tab using window.open and want to automatically fill the value of password field in the newly opened tab but my code is only opening new tab and not filling the password field value.

var n = window.open('https://withsit.com/username=112')

n.document.getElementById("pass1").value="Username123";

Comment: The popup needs to be from the same domain as the page you are calling it from.

Comment: any other way to do this?

Comment: Where is this password coming from, and are you in control of both websites? I ask, because this sounds incredibly insecure.